# Oracle PL/SQL Procedure Error while checking IF table EXISTS in schema

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, execute-immediate

I am using SQL Developer Tool to create a procedure  that checks if table named TRANSPORT_PRODUCT exists, if it does then truncate it, if it does not then create it.

Scenario 1: when TRANSPORT_PRODUCT does not exists in the schema and i compile the procedure, I get the following error while compiling the procedure

```
Error(44,2): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(44,14): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Scenario 2: 
If I create table TRANSPORT_PRODUCT and then create the procedure and run,everything looks fine except that I use the following query inside the procedure to check if the table exists , where variable TABLE_EXISTS in initialised to 0,

```
select  COUNT(*) INTO   TABLE_EXISTS from    user_tables where   table_name= TABLE_NAME;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('IF 0 THEN TABLE DOES NOT EXISTS ELSE TABLE EXISTS -'||TO_CHAR(TABLE_EXISTS,99));
```

A value 48 is stores in TABLE_EXISTS .. that is totally weird to me :(

Scenario 3:
If I create TRANSPORT_PRODUCT table and then create the procedure, Drop the TRANSPORT_PRODUCT  and run the procedure , I get the following message , I am not sure
why is the procedure dependant on the table !

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object XAAL5.EXPORT_PRODUCT is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

My procedure:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EXPORT_PRODUCT IS
        TABLE_NAME      VARCHAR2(50) NULL;
        TABLE_EXISTS    INTEGER:=0;
        TRUNC_TABLE     VARCHAR2(50) NULL;
        CREATE_TABLE    VARCHAR2(1000) NULL;
    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Procedure Start Time :' || to_char(systimestamp,'DD-MM-YY HH:MM:SS'));

        TABLE_NAME:='TRANSPORT_PRODUCT';

        select  COUNT(*) INTO   TABLE_EXISTS from    user_tables where   table_name= TABLE_NAME;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('IF 0 THEN TABLE DOES NOT EXISTS ELSE TABLE EXISTS -'||TO_CHAR(TABLE_EXISTS,99));

        IF (TABLE_EXISTS<>0) THEN
            BEGIN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TABLE_NAME||' TRANSPORT_PRODUCT TABLE EXISTS AND WILL BE TRUNCATED');
                TRUNC_TABLE:='truncate table '|| TABLE_NAME;
                --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TRUNC_TABLE);
                execute immediate TRUNC_TABLE;
            END;
        ELSE
            BEGIN 
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TABLE_NAME ||' DOES NOT EXISTS AND WILL BE CREATED');
                CREATE_TABLE:=
                    'CREATE TABLE TRANSPORT_PRODUCT (
                        ROW_NUMBER      NUMBER,             
                        PRODUCTID       VARCHAR2(20), 
                        PRODUCTNAME     VARCHAR2(100), 
                        OWNER           VARCHAR2(20), 
                        DIVISIONID      VARCHAR2(20), 
                        MERCHLEVEL1     VARCHAR2(20), 
                        MERCHLEVEL2     VARCHAR2(20), 
                        MERCHLEVEL3     VARCHAR2(20), 
                        MERCHLEVEL4     VARCHAR2(20), 
                        STREAMID        VARCHAR2(20), 
                        SPECIFICATION   VARCHAR2(20), 
                        SSS             VARCHAR2(20))';
                execute immediate CREATE_TABLE;
            END;
        END IF;

     -- INSERT PRODUCT INTO TRANSPORT_PRODUCT
        INSERT INTO TRANSPORT_PRODUCT (ROW_NUMBER,PRODUCTID,PRODUCTNAME,OWNER, DIVISIONID,MERCHLEVEL1, MERCHLEVEL2, MERCHLEVEL3,MERCHLEVEL4,STREAMID,SPECIFICATION,SSS) 
        SELECT  ROWNUM,
                PRODUCTID,
                PRODUCTNAME,
                OWNER,
                DIVISIONID,
                MERCHLEVEL1,
                MERCHLEVEL2,
                MERCHLEVEL3,
                MERCHLEVEL4,
                STREAMID,
                SPECIFICATION,
                SSS
        FROM PRODUCT; 

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Procedure End Time :' || to_char(systimestamp,'DD-MM-YY HH:MM:SS'));

   exec buildfile('select * from TRANSPORT_PRODUCT where rownum<=500');

      commit;   
    END;
```

Comment: Simply put, your procedure is dependent on the table because you're accessing it statically in your INSERT statement. If the table doesn't exist this has to be dynamic as well.

Comment: @Ben thanks for the explanation and the link ,I have another issue here, its while querying USER_TABLES.

Ideally the following query should store 0 in the variable when table does not exist, but this is storing 48 :(

[select  COUNT(*) INTO   TABLE_EXISTS from    user_tables where   table_name= TABLE_NAME;]

Comment: Why are you creating the dynamically anyway? You could avoid this if your schema was stable. In this case it looks like this logic is only needed once anyway, unless you later drop the table somewhere else. Doing DDL in a procedure is generally not a good idea.

Comment: Don't call your variable `TABLE_NAME` then... the SQL scope takes precedence over the PL/SQL scope as it's happening in SQL. Call your variable `l_table_name` (for local) or something.

Comment: @Kfactor21 - AlexisSTDM has already answered that part?

Comment: @Ben thanks a ton .. both the suggestions worked. although I am still wondering if TABLE_NAME is a keyword in oracle that cause the issue, but I could not find a reference regarding it. If you could provide any link to the variable scope issue it would be very helpful.

Comment: @AlexPoole , I am trying to convince my manager regarding the same, but for now GTT is not an option as the new table will  be sent out as an embedded string to another proc i.e similar to  the last line in my example above. But i am still trying to get a stable schema in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could see The Scenario 2 problem is that you are using the same procedure parameter name TABLE_NAME than the column name of USER_TABLES. And then the query gives you the total number of tables you have in the schema. TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME matchs always.

And I think the same for your procedure. You use the table statically inside the procedure.

Thanks
Regards.

Comment: That was common sense :(((( , how did i miss that , @alexisSTDM thanks for waking me up..

Comment: It doesn't matter I always forget that oracle is not case sensitive. Thanks to you